# numpy.asarray fails for cython memoryview

Tags: numpy, cython, memoryview

I have encountered some strange behavior using numpy.asarray with a memoryview object that I can't explain. Here's a brief example using the cython magic in a jupyter notebook -- I simply make a function that expects two struct array buffers and returns them. One has two ints and the other a long and an int:

```
cdef struct S1:
    int iGroup
    int iOrder

cdef struct S2:
    long iGroup
    int iOrder

def test_struct(S1[:] s1, S2[:] s2):
    return s1, s2
```

Now I make two arrays in python to pass to this function:

```
dt1 = np.dtype([('iGroup', 'i4'), ('iOrder', 'i4')], align=True)
dt2 = np.dtype([('iGroup', 'i8'), ('iOrder', 'i4')], align=True)

a = np.zeros(10, dtype=dt1)
b = np.zeros(10, dtype=dt2)

x, y = test_struct(a,b)

print x
print y

<MemoryView of 'ndarray' object>
<MemoryView of 'ndarray' object>
```

Both are successfully returned as MemoryView objects. Now I want to turn them into a numpy array:

```
np.asarray(x)

array([(0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0),
       (0, 0), (0, 0)], 
      dtype=[('iGroup', '<i4'), ('iOrder', '<i4')])


np.asarray(y)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-204-ca5459515bfd> in <module>()
----> 1 np.asarray(y)

/Users/rok/miniconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.pyc in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    480 
    481     """
--> 482     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    483 
    484 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

TypeError: expected a readable buffer object
```

What am I missing here? Why does this second struct not work? Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried defining the structs as `cdef packed struct`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @DavidW that seems to fix it -- but why?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. It seems relatively poorly documented. Here's some old documentation but it seems to be missing from the current documentation http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HO3iYcMOpmAJ:docs.cython.org/0.14/src/tutorial/numpy.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Comment: And see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html (`align`).

Comment: Right... I was using the `aligned = True` because I was running into problems elsewhere with the packed structs. The error (expected a readable buffer object) just seems very cryptic.